# How to upgrade to JUnit5 for Scala tests using @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])?

Tags: scala, scalatest, junit5

I'm trying to upgrade JUnit from `4.10` to `5.3.1` a Scala project. The project is using Scalatest.  I would like to know what I should replace the following code with now:

`@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])`

From what I know, (based on doing a similar migration in Java), the `@RunWith` annotation needs to be replaced with `@ExtendWith`, but in this case I'm not quite sure what the correct class would be.

Is this at all supported out of the box, or will it require some work?